# How can I stop my mattress from shifting in a border-less bed frame?

Tags: bedroom

My grandparents didn't appreciate their IKEA Duken Bed Frame's edged rampart:

[image]

until they bought a [TEMPUR-Ergo Extend Power Base](https://www.tempurpedic.com/bases-and-foundations/tempur-ergo-extend/v/2563/) that doesn't have one! Every week, the mattress shifts and protrudes, and they must re-position it so that it doesn't overhang the bed frame.

[image]

Comment: Did you / they ask the Tempur dealer about a solution to the problem? Tempur is a serious company, and they should be able to assist.

Answer (score 1):

The mattress will probably stop sliding if you put a sheet of rubber between the mattress and the bed frame. You can buy these sheets intended to be used for rugs on hardwood floors.

Another interesting tip I found on [this page](https://www.chrislovesjulia.com/5-tips-keeping-area-rugs-exactly-want/) is to put lines of hot glue or silicone caulk on the surface. It's intended for carpets, but it would likely work in your case if the lines are big and thick enough. Hot glue is more grippy than silicone, but usually more expensive.

I suspect some of the answers here (regarding rugs) would help:
[How to make slippery rug stay in place](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20706/how-to-make-slippery-rug-stay-in-place/)

Answer (score 0):

How about putting a non-slip mat on the base, and then putting the mattress on that?

Or straps at the head & feet of the bed, going over the mattress and under the frame, or over the mattress and tying to the legs.